Idiom for a situation where a problem has two simultaneous but unrelated causes?
A colleague of mine, who is a software engineer, recently mentioned that while debugging problems he often finds that, for any given symptom he is investigating, there turn out to be two simultaneous faults that would both individually cause the same symptom, so that he finds one fault that would seem to be the cause of the problem, fixes it, and then when the symptom persists, discovers a second fault that also causes the same symptom.
His most recent example was that he was trying to run a packet capture against some network traffic and discovered that both:

The capture buffer he had configured was too small so it would silently discard the larger packets he was looking for, and
The requests he was interested in were being satisfied by a local cache so weren't actually reaching the network in the first place.

Both faults were independent of each other but caused the same end result, that he could not see the results he was trying to capture.
Is there any English idiom or expression to generically describe this situation? I and a few colleagues have racked our brains for a little while but not come up with anything.

I'd have thought at the "crudest" level of fault analysis, almost all software faults manifest the same way ("The program doesn't work"). So I suspect a really good troubleshooter wouldn't want to noise it about that he often finds two faults simultaneously causing "the same" failure, since that suggests his analytical techniques could be improved. But if the two faults really are "independent", it seems unlikely they'd both initially manifest at the same time. And if they really caused a problem, how come the user didn't report whichever came first, before the "lookalike" fault?

With things like human diseases, it can happen that one infection weakens the body, so it falls victim to another disease - perhaps with similar symptoms. I'm no doctor, but I think they refer to that situation as "Disease #1 with complications".

Both situations, at least in what you've described, proceed from the (false) assumption that there was data in the capture buffer. Why wasn't it being displayed? I would call that "getting ahead of yourself" -- neglecting a necessary step: confirming that the buffer had content.

I don't think there's an expression for this. It's just a kind of coincidence.

Shift it to another situation: you miss your flight because your partner's car broke down, but you didn't cut any slack, and wouldn't itself have been a problem if the first hadn't happened, which was either bad luck or a failure to service the car. When you get home, your passport is on the kitchen table, so you couldn't have taken the flight anyway. This is all the result of poor planning, or lack of foresight.

This is not the same as the 'perfect storm', where all contributory factors are essential.
// 'Trouble always comes in threes' is a related adage, but not spot on. Ditto 'It never rains but [what] it pours' ... these address troubles often coming in groups, but don't demand that each one would individually be a sufficient cause for the breakdown.

@FumbleFingers I may be misrepresenting him by saying "he often finds" - he was actually musing that it has happened several times in his career, which is long enough that I think seeing it enough times to wonder if there is an expression to capture it doesn't reflect poorly on his skills! In any event, it is easy to imagine other circumstances that capture the same concept - for instance, a car that won't start both because it is out of fuel and because the spark plugs are broken, or a light that won't turn on because the bulb itself has blown but also that circuit is off at the breaker.

I wouldn't expect "a car that won't start both because it is out of fuel and because the spark plugs are broken", but as a teenager running clapped-out cars, I soon learned that running out of fuel could suck up sediment in the bottom of the tank, which could jam the needle valve in the carburetor, so a petrol can might not get me back on the road. And a light might not turn on because the bulb itself was blown by the same current surge that tripped the circuit breaker. So, yeah - "interconnected, but not obviously so" causes of failure do sometimes coexist.

Sideways: Lubarsky's Law supposedly states there is always one more bug. Luckily, OP's colleague found two of them, but . . .

I'm not sure about a term for that particular occurrence -- but I know the term for software where that happens regularly: A piece of crap.

There is some small support for a word meaning "having many causes" being polycausal.   And that seems to fit here, to use medical terminology.  It's monosymptomatic but polycausal.

@stevesliva I am skeptical of the term polycausal having any substantial currency, medical or otherwise. I say this because 1.) web searches for the term seem mostly to yield online dictionary entries that are self-referential, and 2.) the meaning of causal is "acting as a cause" (not "having a cause"), and thus one would think that polycausal would also relate to acting as a cause, in some "more-than-one" sense, rather than having causes. I will close by noting that there already is an established medical term meaning "having multiple causes," and that term is multifactorial.

I don’t know whether this really answers your question, but, tangentially, I’ve been hearing “Two things can be true at once” (or “… at the same time”) a lot recently — generally in response to a question like “Are they malicious or incompetent?”

Not an idiom, but more generally it's accurate to say that in this case the buggy behavior is overdetermined.
According to Oxford:

An event is overdetermined if there exist more than one antecedent events, any of which would be a sufficient condition for the event occurring. Analogously, a conclusion is overdetermined if it can be proved in any of a number of independent ways.

If you poison somebody fatally, and I immediately stab them in the neck, their death is overdetermined.
FWIW, "overdetermination" is fun to pronounce.

Overdetermined is probably the best fit in professional mathematics jargon.  Other mathematical terms that apply to this situation are that each fault on its own is sufficient to cause the problem, but neither is necessary to cause the problem.  Other faults might be both necessary and sufficient, or neither necessary nor sufficient, but those are not present in this scenario.

I propose that it is a

double whammy
a situation when two unpleasant things happen at almost the same time
Farmers have faced the double whammy of a rising dollar and falling agricultural prices.

From Cambridge Dictionary, while Merriam-Webster has

double whammy
a combination of two usually adverse forces, circumstances, or effects
With the cold weather and the high cost of heating fuel, homeowners were hit with a double whammy this winter.

In the OP's case the sentence could perhaps be

A colleague suffered a double whammy after finding the buffers were too small, and they were cached anyway.


That doesn't require the two unpleasant things to have the same effect, though, does it?  I think OP is describing two events which are related by more than just near-simultaneity.  (Also, I think that's a fairly colloquial expression, widely understood but unsuitable for formal situations.)

@gidds the question is tagged "idiom".

Of all the answers so far (6), this is the one I'd most likely use in common, every day speech (British English).

Double whammy expresses a combination of causes, but OP's asking for alternative causes, if I understand correctly.

Another phrase along these lines is a "one-two punch", although both this and "double whammy" really just indicate that two bad things are happening in quick succession, not necessarily that the causes are entirely unrelated or that the effects are the same.

You could perhaps call this a perfect storm, which describes a combination of bad events that produces something worse than any one individually. The term describes an unusual meteorological event where multiple independent storm systems combine into a much more powerful one. More generally, it connotes an unusual coincidence of multiple bad things happening at once, and the synergy between them.
It might not quite capture the notion of two independent causes resulting in the the same bad outcome, since the outcome is actually the same with one or both causes. It could be interpreted as suggesting that the outcome is in a way worse than with either fault individually, though, since although neither cause makes the problem itself worse, having both masks the issue and makes it harder to diagnose.
Another related term connoting the idea that the fault requires both (not either) underlying cause is to reference the "swiss cheese model" of failure. You can use multiple layers of fault protection, each of which catches most errors (but has a few holes like a piece of swiss cheese), but problems can still happen when the "holes align" in the layers of swiss cheese.

No, because "perfect storm" is for two or more causes all of which are necessary, and none of which are sufficient.  The OP seeks an idiom where any of the causes is sufficient.

Maybe a layered problem
In this video, the narrator presents the various issues of the Mark 14 torpedo, which was designed in 1931 and by the end of the war became a reliable weapon. In the meantime however, it was plagued by multiple problems, each of which made it quite inefficient.
The creator of the video chose the following title for the video: The Mark 14 Torpedo - Failure is Like Onions
The onion-part is a quip relating to the issues which plagued the torpedo, each of which individually causes a problem. And fixing one, only reveals the next one.

It runs too deep, thus misses the target entirely
Once it ran at a correct depth, it exploded prematurely due to problems with the magnetic exploder
Once the magnetic exploder was deactivated, it became apparent that the contact fuse did not work properly leading to hull thuds instead of sinkings


While this may apply in some cases, it likely doesn't apply to others where the issues are not layered but are "siblings"

The issues described in my example, were layered only in the sense, that when one was fixed the next one became apparent. However, there is definitely the case here, that one issue might mask the other, e.g., a non-operating contact fuse is masked when the torpedo runs too deep and never contacts the target. Only when the depth issue is fixed, can the fusing issue become apparent. From an end result perspective, they are independent; from a trouble shooting perspective, they are layered.

In engineering, the standard terminology for this (which is called out in the ISO-26262 standard) is
Multiple-point fault
A multiple-point fault can then, under the right (or wrong!) circumstances, lead to a "multiple-point failure". Faults do not necessarily cause a failure, of course.
If this relates to a technical situation (as per your examples), this is the ISO-standard correct way to refer to the situation.  Other answers are correct linguistically or idiomatically, but this is the phrase you want for a technical situation.

I don't think this describes the OP's scenario. According to the linked definition, a multiple point fault must be accompanied by other faults before it causes a failure. In the OP's scenario, either fault individually causes failure whether the other is present or not - they are single-point faults that both cause the same failure.

If there was one true issue and multiple things you thought could be the issue but weren't, then you have one root cause...

The fundamental reason for the occurrence of a problem

...and one (or more) red herring

Something that distracts attention from the real issue

Or maybe both issues are red herrings and you've not yet found the root cause.
Or maybe you have multiple root causes, any one of which would cause the same issue depending which you hit first. Simply describing it as multiple root causes seems a good choice (albeit not very glamorous) as there's a whole field of Root Cause Analysis which aims to identify which of many root causes is to blame for a given failure mode.
If you're at the point of understanding the problem before you even have a list of potential root causes, you might steal a medical term and characterise the bug as idiopathic

Arising spontaneously or from an obscure or unknown cause


Three different scenarios are presented here; the question is only about the middle one.

@jsw29 In the OP's example they describe having two root causes, sure that's the middle case I've presented. But they also say that in this specific situation the 1st option was impossible because "[requests] weren't actually reaching the network in the first place", so that diagnosis was a red herring as in my first description. All of these options are related, and dependent only on the degree to which you understand the actual root cause.

Please keep answers to one suggestion apiece

There are a handful of programming jargon terms for various bug situations, and the one you describe nearly fits under the definition of a mandelbug.
From Wikipedia:

A mandelbug (named after Benoît Mandelbrot's fractal) is a bug whose causes are so complex it defies repair, or makes its behavior appear chaotic or even non-deterministic.[2] The term also refers to a bug that exhibits fractal behavior (that is, self-similarity) by revealing more bugs (the deeper a developer goes into the code to fix it the more bugs they find).

In this case, the act of investigating this bug caused multiple causes to be discovered with the same ultimate failure symptom. So, while not a perfect fit, this is the term for how I'd describe the situation to my collogues.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heisenbug#See_also

Specifically for engineering I might describe this as a corner case:

a corner case ... involves a problem or situation that occurs only outside normal operating parameters — specifically one that manifests itself when multiple environmental variables or conditions are simultaneously at extreme levels, even though each parameter is within the specified range for that parameter.

(Emphasis mine.)
The term is a kind of higher-order extension of an edge case. An edge case is where a single parameter or operating condition is at an extreme, and only causes issues when it is at that extreme. A corner case is when two (or more) parameters are at an extreme, hence, corner.

It seems to me that you ran an uncontrolled experiment (or maybe an out-of-control experiment).

A controlled experiment is one in which everything is held constant
except for one
variable. —ThoughtCo

You had two variables at play — buffer size and caching — so there would be no way of knowing which one(s) caused the fail without revisiting the problem, as your colleague did, to fix one thing and then the other.
